# backbone date + other parameters sorting

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

so, this works:

```
comparator: function(model) {
  if(this.activeSort == "time_created") {
    return -(Date.parse(model.get('time_created')) || 1);
  } else {
    var sort = [ 
      model.get('title'), 
      model.get('category'), 
    ];
    return sort;
  }
}
```

but if I want to sort by "time_created" and the other parameters (title, category), the sorting no longer works. I can't figure it out!

Basically, I want this to work:

```
comparator: function(model) {
  if(this.activeSort == "time_created") {
    var sort = [ 
      // date descending
      -(Date.parse(model.get('time_created')) || 1), 
      model.get('title'), 
      model.get('category'), 
    ];
    return sort;
  } else {
    var sort = [ 
      model.get('title'), 
      model.get('category'), 
    ];
    return sort;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be using a two-argument comparator. Returning an array is not a good way to make a single-argument comparator work as a multi-attribute comparator, mostly because it simply doesn't work reliably (as you've found out).

So:

```
comparator: function(o1, o2) {
  var v1, v2;

  if (this.activeSort == "time_created") {
    v1 = Date.parse(o1.get("time_created")) || 1;
    v2 = Date.parse(o2.get("time_created")) || 1;
    if (v1 > v2)
      return -1;
    if (v2 > v1)
      return 1;
  }

  v1 = o1.get("title");
  v2 = o2.get("title");
  if (v1 < v2)
    return -1;
  if (v2 < v1)
    return 1;

  v1 = o1.get("category");
  v2 = o2.get("category");
  if (v1 < v2)
    return -1;
  if (v2 < v1)
    return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is what I was about to say. Comparing arrays using `<` or `>` stringifies the arrays first and that just makes a big nasty mess. You can get around that problem if you can stringify the arrays yourself using fixed-length records internally but that's just nasty.

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising but I am still getting the same results. title and category sort works fine, the time sort is only sorted by time with this code. I'm using the latest versions of jquery, underscore and backbone. I am going to dig into this a bit more and post with more details.

Comment: never mind, my timestamps were all over the place, so the grouping would look random, after I rounded down the timestamp to the nearest day the sorting worked just fine!

Comment: v2 = (Date.parse(o2.get("time_created")) -Date.parse(o2.get("time_created")) % 86400000) || 1;

Comment: going to clean it up a bit more, but thanks for the solution!