# multiple sorting in backbone.js

Tags: sorting, backbone.js

sorting in backbone it's working fine. but i want to sort multiple fields, now am passing sort argument dynamically by clicking sorting headers. i have 5 headers(id,desc,type,category,hierarchy). when i click any headers it's sort by ascending and next click descending but problem is sort by only one attribute i want to multiple attribute pass to collection and maintain a previous sorting order and again sort till the data are relative.

in collection:

```
   sortAsc: function(sortField) {
       var key = sortField;
        this.comparator = function(model) {
            return model.get(key);
        };  
        this.sort();
    },

    sortDesc: function(sortField) {
        var key = sortField;
        this.comparator = function(a, b) {
            a = a.get(key);
            b = b.get(key);
            return a < b ?  1 : a > b ? -1 : 0;
        }
        this.sort();
    },
```

view:     called when click header(click event) and elem id is (dynamically change on click) ID,,Desc,Category,Type and Hierarchy.

```
        sortItems: function(e) {            
        if ( currentClass.indexOf("ascending")>0 ) {
            this.currentcollection.sortAsc(elem.id);
        }

        else {
            this.currentcollection.sortDesc(elem.id);
        }

    },
```

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924690/backbone-date-other-parameters-sorting

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that receives comparators array and return a composite comparator so  that  comparators[n] is the tie breaker of comparator[n-1]

```
var createCompositeComparators = function(comparators){
  return function(a,b){
     var i = 0;
     var tempResult = 0;
     for(i=0; i<comparators.length; i++){
        tempResult = comparators[i](a,b);
        if (tempResult !== 0 ) return tempResult;
     }
     return tempResult;
  };
};
```

And a function that creates a comparator from a field, it should accept `[+|-]fieldName` (e.g. +count or -count)

```
var createFieldComparator = function(fullField){
  var field = fullField.substring(1);
  var desc = fullField.substring(0,1) === "-" ? -1 : 1;
  return function(a, b) {
        return  desc * (a.get(field) - b.get(field));
    };
}
```

to finalize with the sortByFields:

```
sortByFields: function(sortFields){ // array
  var comparators = _.map(sortFields, createFieldComparator);//Create a list of comparators from a list of fields in the form of [+|-]field
  this.comparator = createCompositeComparators(comparators);
  this.sort();
}
```

To use it just send an array of fields

```
collection.sortByFields(["+Category", "-ID"]);
```

Off course this code is not production ready... not tested